# Jamfile - "Unknow rule" - How to read into it

Tags: linux, mingw, autoconf, jam

I am trying to compile this project - It compiles perfectly in
Linux(ubuntu). But I want it to work on Windows. So I installed MinGW
(which comes with Jamplus installed) - and went ahead installing all the
libs needed for the project. After doing that (phew!) - I downloaded the
src of this project and did './autogen' + './configure -prefix=/mingw' and
then when I do jam, I get "unknown rule" warning. **Is it because they are
unix commands and MinGW is not able to understand it?? Or is it jam? It is not able to understand lines like "UseAutoconf" and "Install Docs" - I am relatively new to Jam build system any help will be appreciated. Thanks.**

Here is the jamfile - http://pastebin.com/z3FsMjDt

http://i1268.photobucket.com/albums/jj568/amitahire/jam-minggw.png

And also when I did ./autogen - it said

> configure.ac:144: warning: AC_LANG_CONFTEST: no AC_LANG_SOURCE call
>   detected in body
>   /mingw/src/autoconf/26/autoconf2.5-2.68-1/src/autoconf-2.68/lib/autoconf/lang.m4:194:
>   AC_LANG_CONFTEST is expanded from...
>   /mingw/src/autoconf/26/autoconf2.5-2.68-1/src/autoconf-2.68/lib/autoconf/general.m4:2662:
>   _AC_LINK_IFELSE is expanded from... /mingw/src/autoconf/26/autoconf2.5-2.68-1/src/autoconf-2.68/lib/autoconf/general.m4:2679:
>   AC_LINK_IFELSE is expanded from... mk/autoconf/np_findlib.m4:3:
>   NP_FINDLIB is expanded from... configure.ac:144: the top level

another six more of these. But I ignored it and went ahead with the configure progress which had no problem.

**EDIT - THIS SEEMS TO SOLVE THE ISSUE.**

This particular project (i suppose) isnt compiling with Jamplus 0.3. Hence when I tried with Jam 2.5 (or Ftjam) it compiles.

Answer (score 0):

The console output contains several error messages like "Jamfile.jam: No such file or directory". I don't use jam on Windows, but AFAIK the standard (Perforce) jam expects jamfiles to be named just "Jamfile" on Windows as well. My guess is that Jamplus simply isn't compatible with the generated build system. Renaming the jamfiles may help, but installing the jam the build system expects is probably the safest solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I sorted the "no such file" by changing the file extension to .jam ( or could have done it in configure file as well). But main problem is that its not compiling and the warning. I just checked my linux installation has jam 2.5 and windows has jamplus...I think I should try installing Jam.